# VirtualBox: route specific host traffic to a specific network interface on guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing

I use VirtualBox with a Linux Host and a Windows Guest.

On the Windows Guest, there is a software which sets up access to a specific VPN; this specific software only runs on Windows.

I would like to route the traffic from the Linux Host, for specific IP addresses, to the Windows Guest's virtual network interface created by this software for the VPN.

I tried several options, such as VirtualBox's Host-Only adapter to link the Host to the Guest and then route the traffic to the VPN network interface in the Windows Guest but for the latter the Routing Service cannot be started.

Any help?

Comment: If it is possible then it should be done with a network level driver to filter network packets.